# Hide Keyboard when user taps outside the text field in UITableView and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios5

My UIViewController hierarchy is as follows

```
UIView
    UIScrollView
        UITableView
            UITableViewCell
                UITextField
```

The UITableView is added to the view controller programmatically.
I want to hide keyboard when user taps outside UTTextField either on the view or on the UITableView
I am executing some methods when user taps on other UITableView rows

I tried

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

UIScrollView doesn't send the touch events.

I tried adding Tap gesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

but with TapGesture, hides the following event

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

are there any other possible ways to hide the keyboard?

Comment: In any case you need to detect event and use `
    [txtfield resignFirstResponder];` without getting touch event or detect any event you are not able to do that..

Comment: do u want to resign keypads if user touches view

Comment: Just add the gesture recogniser to the tables background: [tableview.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];  This means the didSelectRowAtIndexPath will still work.

Answer (score 2):

use the code :  [self.view endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 1):

use the UITextFieldDelegate
and the method

```
– textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField*) txtField
{

[txtField resignKeyPads];
return YES:
}
```

this can also done by the scrolview delgate too

```
-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //resign all keypads of all textfields use array containing keypads
}
```

one thing more is change the class of UIView to UIControl and make a method IBAction and connect the UIControl touchupInside to that ibaction, it will resign keypads

Comment: you mean prevent hiding if scrolview scrolled?

Comment: `– textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField*)txtField` hides keypad only when user taps return key. to use scrollview delegate `-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` scroll appears for some conditions and doesn't for some conditions at runtime

Comment: and one other thing is make a UIControlClass see answer edited

Comment: if not understand then ping me again

Comment: I think its not the right option to change the UIView to a UIControl and adding touchupInside event. This is my last option. thanks man. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: why it is not right option. all your things remains same. it's a subclass of UIView and doesn't affect anything else

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still use tap gestures you need to add the gesture recogniser to the table background like so:

```
[tableView.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

This will prevent the hiding of:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: tried adding tap gesture to backgroundView not able to capture tap events. here is my code `[[optionsTableView backgroundView] addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a gesture recognizer on the background view you need to make sure it has one.

Add

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not call when UITableview is Edit Mode. So you suppose to create custom gesture event to handle the same.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//cell design code goes here.
 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
//tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];
 return cell; 
} 
//Handle the click event 
-(void) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{ 
[self.view endEditing:YES]; 
UITableViewCell * cell =(UITableViewCell*) sender.view; 
//get the selected table indexpath. 
NSIndexPath * indexPath= [tblCart indexPathForCell:cell]; //to handle the scroll
tblCart scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]; 
NSLog(@"Comming"); 
}
```